# Why am I getting "no matching function for call to '…'" with template function?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, overload-resolution, explicit-instantiation

With the below code:

**materia.h:**

```
#ifndef MATERIA_H
#define MATERIA_H

class material
{
public:
  template <class type>
  static material* MakeMaterial(typename type::configtype, long);
  template <class type>
  void CreateNaturalForm(typename type::configtype, long);
  … 
};

template <class type>
material* material::MakeMaterial(typename type::configtype Config, long Volume)
{
  return type::Spawn(Config, Volume);
}

#endif
```

**materias.h:**

```
#ifndef MATERIAS_H
#define MATERIAS_H

#include "materia.h"
#include "confdef.h"

class solid : public material {
public:
  typedef solidmaterial configtype;
  … 
};

template material* material::MakeMaterial<solid>(solidmaterial, long);

template <class type>
void material::CreateNaturalForm(typename type::configtype Config, long Volume)
{
  … 
  MakeMaterial(Config, Volume); // Error here
  … 
}

template void material::CreateNaturalForm<solid>(solidmaterial, long);

#endif
```

**confdef.h:**

```
#ifndef CONFDEF_H
#define CONFDEF_H

enum solidmaterial {
  WOOD,
  … 
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "materia.h"
#include "materias.h"
#include "confdef.h"

int main()
{
  material::MakeMaterial(WOOD, 500); // Same error here
}
```

([Here](http://goo.gl/vcybSJ)'s an online version of the above code that reproduces the error.)

I get the following compilation error message on the commented line:

> No matching function for call to 'MakeMaterial'

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the explicit instantiation allow the compiler to see the correct function?

The code compiles if I write `MakeMaterial<solid>` explicitly, but the whole point here is to deduce `type` from the `Config` argument. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please make it compile, first (Read and understand the error message, or ask what an error message means).

Comment: That should not be the first one (or you might have ignored a warning)

Comment: @DieterLücking "Candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'type'"

Comment: Just replace two `template` by `template<>``for specialization

Comment: What is the purpose of the first function argument to `MakeMaterial`? Is an instance of something really required, or is just the type needed?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The enum value itself is required. The enum _type_ defines which `material` subclass to use.

Comment: Would it help then to just use `solidmaterial` (the enum type) as type for the argument, and ditch the templating?

Comment: Shouldn't g++ emit an diagnostic message omitting the '<>' in a specialization?

Comment: @DieterLücking Those are instantiations, not specializations. A specialization is not good here because the body is always simply `return type::Spawn(Config, Volume);`, only the template parameter changes.

Comment: The first error should be `error: ‘MakeMaterial’ was not declared in this scope``(it's a static function of `class material`

Answer (score 2):

In the call

```
MakeMaterial(Config, Volume); // Error here
```

the compiler is asked to find a match where `type::configtype` in the function template, is the type of `Config`.

But nothing tells the compiler what to match `type` to: this is not an explicit instantiation.

In general there could be hundreds of types that `type` could be matched to, where `type::configtype` would be the type of `Config`. C++ does not support the special case where there is only one such possible type.

How to fix that depends on what you meant to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to make the compiler deduce `type` from the type of `Config`. With the explicit instantiation I'm telling that if `Config` is of type `solidmaterial` then `type` is `solid`. Shouldn't what I'm calling in `main` be completely unambiguous?

Comment: @zenith: OK, you're *trying* say that. But the compiler only sees that this is one possibility. You could define an arbitrary number of other possibilities that would have the same `T::configtype`.